# Is there a UK PhD scholarship for international students that pays as much as a particular city's average annual salary?

Tags: funding, united-kingdom, salary

After checking out PhD stipends offered by various UK universities, I've come to the conclusion that they are way below the average annual salary.

I realize now that this is normal. At Durham, for instance, the most competitive studentship is valued only at GBP 14,000+ annually.

Are there scholarships in the UK that pays as much as a particular city's average annual salary?

Are there scholarships that are as generous as Vanier (CAD 50,000 annually) and Trillium (CAD 40,000 annually) in Canada?

Comment: Why do you think that a PhD student should be paid at some 'average' annual salary?

Comment: @JonCuster Why not?

Comment: @Orion because is very qualified workforce which is autolearning 99.9% of the time, and in many contracts his/her production is property of the institution that provides the fellowship

Comment: *Of course* stipends are below the average salary just about everywhere—even the Vanier and Trillium are probably below market salary. Stipends are not meant to be a salary, but a means of providing support for the student while they are enrolled as a graduate student.

Comment: If you think a PhD scholarship should be an average wage, you're sorely mistaken. In Australia, the average wage is about $78k, do you think that any student should be paid $78k when they're learning to become a professional? Doing your PhD isn't supposed to be about the money that you earn.

Comment: @Orion - well, because many people who are productive in real jobs are not paid the (average, median, mode) salary. A student, still learning their trade, is by definition not as productive as a graduated PhD working as a professor or industry researcher (who likely are paid more than the average locally). You need enough money to live on, not be 'average' relative to the surrounding population. I was not rich as a grad student, but lived just fine on a 'below average' salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among many studentships provided by Universities in the UK and major research councils (through Centers for Doctoral Training), most programs will only cover student fees and some moderate living expenses which may not be comparable with the median salary in the region. However, you should bear in mind, that the stipends are usually tax-free, and there are significant discounts for students (e.g. train tickets, council tax) helping to reduce the expenses.

To answer your question formally, [Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions PhD Funding](https://www.findaphd.com/funding/guides/marie-sklodowska-curie-actions-msca-phd-funding.aspx) provides about €3,110 per month for living expenses, which will exceed the median salary in almost every county in the UK, expect the greater London perhaps.

Comment: Train ticket discounts in the UK for students? Where? There were none when I was there for monthly tickets. Towards the end of my PhD, South Yorkshire increased the age limit for people in full time education so that university students could get a reduced monthly ticket. However if you had to get a national rail monthly ticket, you ended up paying the same full fee... - Bus reductions were also city dependent. Student discounts existed in Sheffield but not in Leeds for example.

Comment: @DetlevCM Full-time students in the UK are eligible for 16-25 travel card (even if they are older than 25), which provides 30% discount for off-peak tickets.

Comment: Except that they aren't applicable for season tickets. And one might even go a bit further than call them a bit of a scam - I had one, a single time during my undergraduate degree when I replaced my passport and had to go to London - the sole usage. When I tried to use it again, I couldn't because the distance travelled was too short (anytime return) or it wasn't applicable to the train ticket desired (first class travel to the airport which took 2 hours and at full price for first class over second class was only 8-10£ more at the time). - So nice in theory, useless in reality.

Comment: @DetlevCM I feel your pain - it's a shame they don't combine a 18-25 discount with the season ticket discount. Well, some services do: https://www.southernrailway.com/tickets/discounts-and-railcards/unizone And a discount for one-off tickets is still a discount, which is often quite useful in my opinon. And the 100% discount for the council tax is nice, too.

Comment: The discount is good if you can get it (but the same with a normal railcard...). It seems like only advance long distance travels are covered - given UK railway prices, a luxury expense and not a regular work/study commute. The council tax discount is good - but then I wouldn't look at this as being so special - other countries offer similar "advantages", some offer more.

Comment: @DetlevCM Who ever said these discounts are special? It seems like you are beating a strawman here. This is just something students get in the UK which makes their life a bit easier even on a lower stipend compared to e.g. a fully tax-paying postdoc.

Comment: Yes, except that for the season ticket that you actually need to get to the university they don't apply. There is no point in theoretical discounts that the majority of students cannot get.